# Check headers in PHP cURL server response

Tags: php, curl

I've been using PHP curl to get data I need from remote website. Here is the cURL function I used:

```
function get_content($adr)  
    {  
       $ch = curl_init();  

       curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $adr);  
       curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.13) Gecko/20080311 Firefox/2.0.0.13');
       curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);  

       ob_start();  

       curl_exec ($ch);  
       curl_close ($ch);  
       $string = ob_get_contents();  

       ob_end_clean();  

       return $string;      

    }  
$myrul = "http://remoteurl.com";
$result = get_content($myrul);
```

But how do I get the headers for the response?

Comment: is there a question hidden in there somewhere?

Comment: I assume it's "how do I see the headers returned from the `curl_exec()` function?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If my comment above is correct, change:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
```

to:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
```

and parse the returned headers out however you see fit.  Note that just changing the above in your function will return both headers **and** content, so if you want **only** headers returned:

```
function http_head_curl($url,$timeout=10)
{
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, $timeout); // in seconds
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $res = curl_exec($ch);
    if ($res === false) {
        throw new RuntimeException("cURL exception: ".curl_errno($ch).": ".curl_error($ch));
    }
    return trim($res);
}
```